# Django Cookie Cutter SSL

Tags: python, django

How do I disable the automatic SSL redirect in pydanny's- django cookie cutter?
I've commented out the line below but it still does not work?

SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = env.bool("DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT", default=False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting default to False should do it.

You can also remove the middleware in the middleware section.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # Make sure djangosecure.middleware.SecurityMiddleware is listed first
    'djangosecure.middleware.SecurityMiddleware',
) + MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES
```